# Troubleshooting CSS padding in responsive design

Tags: css, padding, fluid-layout

This simple HTML5 layout is intended to have a navigation bar on the left with body text floated alongside it (using percentages rather than pixels for a fluid, responsive design - calculations are in comments within the CSS.)

http://www.wturrell.co.uk/stackoverflow/20110615-01.html

The widths of elements inside the 'page' div add up to 100% exactly. I want to add padding to certain elements, in this case the nav.  If I remove all the padding, they float correctly, but more than 1 or 2 pixels of padding (regardless of what units it's specified in) and it breaks.  I don't understand why this is breaking the layout as it's padding so surely shouldn't alter the overall size of the block?

What have I missed?

**Update - solution:**
http://www.wturrell.co.uk/stackoverflow/20110615-02.html

(Element display width = width **plus** border **plus** padding. Navigation should be nominal 200 pixels in total with 20px padding on right, so for fluid design, width = 180/900*100 or 20%, padding = 20/900*100 or 2.222% and body text remains 700/900*100 or 77.777%.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the [**CSS box model**](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html), the `padding` is added to the `width` to get the overall size of the box. In your case, if the width percentages add up to 100%, even 1px would mean that the content overflows.

Try setting the padding in percentages and take that into account when adding them up or leave a buffer of 1 or 2 percent at the edges and add the small paddings in pixels.

Comment: Thanks (also to @sandeep and @thirtydot) - for some reason I'd begun to think the reverse and assume increasing the padding meant a reduction in the content width.. I've edited the question to include a fixed version + new calculations.

Answer (score 7):

Firstly, you need to add a doctype to trigger Standards Mode. Without this, your page will use [Quirks Mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quirks_mode), which will cause *diabolical problems* in particularly Internet Explorer.

Add as your very first line:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Next, @Alex Ciminian's answer is correct concerning the box model (`padding` is not considered part of `width`). You can either reduce the `width` by exactly the amount of `padding`, or:

Use `box-sizing: border-box`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/box-sizing

You would add it to any elements where you'd like the `padding` to be included inside the calculation of the `width`:

```
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
box-sizing: border-box;
```

For more details about this, see: http://css-tricks.com/box-sizing/

The browser support for this property is good: http://caniuse.com/css3-boxsizing - everywhere but IE6/7.

Comment: Cool, didn't know about box-sizing :).

Answer (score 3):

@williant; Alex is right `padding & border` add `width` to an element. So, adjust `width` according to the `padding`.

**css:**

```
#page nav {
    clear: both;
    display: inline;
    float: left;
    padding: 0 10% 0 0;
    width: 12.2222%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could either try using `box-sizing: border-box;` or set `max-width:100%` and/or `max-height:100%;`.

The max-width and max-height css option is compatible with older versions of IE if you want to try and keep compatibility.

EDIT:

Use the code below to use box-sizing across browsers:

```
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
box-sizing: border-box;
```